# MySQL - Undefined column in temporary table

Tags: mysql

I created a stored procedure to get a list of dates between 2 given dates into a temporary table. That temporary table should have 2 columns : id of type int and day of type date. The problem is that on output i only get the day column, the id column being undefined.
What i am doing wrong?

```
DELIMITER $$    
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `days`(IN dateStart DATE, IN dateEnd DATE)
BEGIN

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS date_range (id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, day DATE);

    Delete from date_range;

    WHILE dateStart <= dateEnd DO
      INSERT INTO date_range(day) VALUES (dateStart);
      SET dateStart = DATE_ADD(dateStart, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    END WHILE;
END
```

This is the call and the output of the stored procedure:
[image]

Comment: Don't you select anything at the end of your procedure?

Comment: @juergend no. i call the procedure like this : `call days('2014-07-01', '2014-07-31');
SELECT * FROM date_range;`

Comment: @juergend i updated the description of my question by adding a screen with the output of the stored procedure. The id column is missing.

Comment: Yes, I get that. But it is not missing when I test it in my environment

Comment: @juergend looks like that a restart of the environment solved the problem.

Comment: Please post that as an answer. It may be useful for future visitors

Answer (score 1):

After dropping the stored procedure and after that, creating a new stored procedure with the same name as the dropped one, it is necessary to restart MySql workbench. Restarting the environment solved my problem.